# Server side validation for CKEditor user input (django)

Tags: django, ckeditor

I want to use CKEditor for my app where where users(anyone) can post articles but I am not sure if it is safe. I have to mark the text from CKEditor as 'Safe' while rendering in django templates to get expected results. As per Django documentation it is not recommended to turn off escaping input text from unknown sources. Even CKEditor mentions that the input should be a clean HTML.

Can CKEditor be used for my use case? if so I need some suggestions to avoid any security issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a CKEditor widget that sanitizes your untrusted input with e.g. Bleach library after it is added. Adjust your tags per your needs:

```
import bleach
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

ALLOWED_TAGS = set(bleach.ALLOWED_TAGS + [ 
    'a', 'blockquote', 'code', 'del', 'dd', 'dl', 'dt', 
    'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'i', 'img', 'kbd', 
    'li', 'ol', 'ul', 'p', 'pre', 's', 'sup', 'sub', 'em', 
    'strong', 'strike', 'ul', 'br', 'hr' ]) 

ALLOWED_STYLES = set(bleach.ALLOWED_STYLES + [ 
    'color', 'background-color', 'font', 'font-weight', 
    'height', 'max-height', 'min-height', 
    'width', 'max-width', 'min-width', ]) 

ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = {}   
ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES.update(bleach.ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES) 
ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES.update({ 
    '*': ['class', 'title'], 
    'a': ['href', 'rel'], 
    'img': ['alt', 'src', 'width', 'height', 'align', 'style'], 
})


def bleach_clean(html): 
    """ Cleans given HTML with bleach.clean() """ 
    return bleach.clean(
        html, 
        tags=ALLOWED_TAGS, 
        attributes=ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES, 
        styles=ALLOWED_STYLES, 
        strip=True
    ) 


class RichTextBleachField(RichTextField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(RichTextBleachField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
    def to_python(self, value): 
        return bleach_clean(value)
```

We use this for some security constrained projects and it works well. Bleach also knows how to fix broken HTML so we get free validation with the field that is very easy to use with models and forms alike.

Comment: Thanks! really appreciate it. this should solve my problem since you are already using it. will try it in the next couple of days. will update you.

Comment: tried it just now.. i was about to remove this feature but thanks to you its now part of my project.

Comment: Great to hear! Have a merry Xmas and good luck to your project.